# Deduce information about $\mathrm{E} |X|$ and /or $\mathrm{Var} |X|$ from $\mathrm{E} X$ and $\mathrm{Var} X$

Tags: probability

The general question is if we are given $\mathrm{E} X$ and $\mathrm{Var} X$ for some random variable $X$, can we deduce some information about $|X|$, such as bounds on $\mathrm{E} |X|$ and $\mathrm{Var} |X|$? Note that Chebyshev's and Markov's inequality only provide information about $\mathrm{P} (|X| \geq a)$.

For example, 
let $X_t, t \geq 0$ be a stochastic process and $a, b, c, d>0$.
Suppose we know
$$
    \mathrm{E}(X_t)=-a e^{-b t} \!\ 
$$
and
$$
\mathrm{Var} (X_t )
= c\left( 1 - e^{-d t} \right). 
$$

Can we deduce some information about $\mathrm{E} |X_t|$ and $\mathrm{Var} |X_t|$, such as bounds on them?

Does $\mathrm{E} |X_t|$ also non-decrease as $t \to \infty$, as $\mathrm{E} X_t$ does? 
Does $\mathrm{Var} |X_t|$ also non-decrease as $t \to \infty$, as $\mathrm{Var} X_t$ does?

When $X_t$ is normally distributed, $X_t$ is [folded normally distributed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Folded_normal_distribution).Analyzing monotonicity of $\mathrm{E} |X_t|$ and $\mathrm{Var} |X_t|$ is still hard for me to do.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need more information about the distribution of $X_t$ to obtain non-trivial bounds. Without any assumptions, I can only find the following simple bounds.

Since $\left|\cdot\right|$ is convex, we have $$\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_t\right|\right]\geq\left|\mathbb{E}\left[X_t\right]\right|= ae^{-bt}.$$ Furthermore, we can write $$\mathbb{E}\left[X_t\right]^2+\mathrm{var}\left[X_t\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[X_t^2\right]=\mathbb{E}\left[\left|X_t\right|\right]^2+\mathrm{var}\left[\left|X_t\right|\right].$$ Therefore, $$\mathrm{var}\left[\left|X_t\right|\right]\leq \mathrm{var}\left[X_t\right]=c\left(1-e^{-dt}\right).$$